# Are Feistel ciphers subject to the birthday bound?

Tags: feistel-network, birthday-attack

[This paper](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2004/CRYPTO/1665/1665.pdf) seems to be saying that a balanced Feistel cipher can be broken when an adversary has $2^{0.5 \cdot n}$ pairs of plaintext and cipher text blocks where $n$ is the block size in bits. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to focus on the stated assumptions in the paper.

It is saying that you need 6 or more rounds to get high security against attacks with no more than $2^{n}$ plaintext ciphertext pairs for a classical (balanced) feistel cipher with truly randomly chosen round functions. This is of course an idealized model for a feistel cipher.

To test your understanding the sentence "In this paper we will show that 5-round random Feistel schemes resist all CPA-2 attacks when m ≪ 2n and that 6-round random Feistel schemes resist all CPCA-2 attacks when m ≪ 2n." is the crucial statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Common *uses* of block ciphers are subject to the birthday bound**, with no exception for Feistel ciphers (which are block ciphers). But the paper cited has no relation to that.

When approaching $2^{0.5\cdot n}$ blocks, collisions between blocks of ciphertext become plausible in [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) and [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB)) modes of operation, and that allows to find the XOR of the following blocks of plaintext (with $m$ blocks, probability of such issue is less than $2^{2m-n-1}$ ). In other modes like [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)), if we see no ciphertext collision after that $2^{0.5\cdot n}$ bound, that's indicative that the plaintext is *not* very random, thus is less likely to be a compressed video than all-zero. These are at least a theoretical attacks for Known Plaintext (CBC..) or Chosen Plaintext (CTR..). That can turn into something remotely practical for $n=64$.

The paper gives asymptotic results on the number of Feistel rounds necessary for large $n$ and ideal round function, comparing to an ideal block cipher under various attack models, and ignoring operating modes. I refer to [kodlu's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54294/555) for more on the paper.